# move one commit to the top of all commits

Tags: git

I've made a commit, `CM`, and then applied several patches, `P1` and `P2`.
So my history looks like

```
C1-C2-CM-P1-P2
```

where `C1` and `C2` are two previous commits.

The problem is that I forgot to create patch for my commit.
How to move my commit `CM` to the top of the commits? The history should look like

```
C1-C2-P1-P2-CM
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you haven't push your branch yet, you can do an interactive rebase:

```
git rebase -i C2
```

You can then  reorder your commits as `P1-P2-CM`, and re-apply them on top of `C2`.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`rebase -i`](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History).

```
$ git rebase -i HEAD~5
```

It will open your text editor with the latest 5 commits. Reorder the commits in the order you want, then save and close.

Comment: HEAD~3 or C2 (as I mention in my answer) should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Do a `git rebase -i C1` and then in the editor that pops up, reorder the commits, save and quit. If there are no conflicts or things, it'll reorder it.

Comment: Why C1? C2 (as I mention in my answer) should be enough here.

Comment: Should be. I just picked the first commit I could see.